# FormData empty while AJAX POST with PDF : SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to use a document info extraction API which takes PDF/JPEG along with "options" json object as FormData. I tried forming the data and do an AJAX Post but it returns 400 error "message": "Required form-data not provided." and the FormData object looks like an empty object with content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". From Postman, I see that the content type should be multipart/formdata with boundary.

```
     var fileuploader=this.byId("fileUploader");
             //var fileB = new File(   fileA, 'canvasImage.png',{ type: 'image/png' } ); 
             jQuery.sap.domById(fileuploader.getId() + "-fu").setAttribute("type", "file");
        data1.append("file",jQuery.sap.domById(fileuploader.getId() + "-fu").files[0]);
         var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(options)], {type : 'application/json'});
data1.append("options",blob);

    jQuery.ajax( {
      url: "/DIC_trial_API/document/jobs",
      data: data1,  "headers": {
                    "Content-Type":undefined,
                    
//                  // "Accept":"*/*",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer "+bearerToken
                    },  
      cache: false,
      //contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      method: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(err) {
console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

Is something wrong with formdata or the post method used?

Comment: A 400 error usually means that the API received your request but couldn't make sense of it. Is the webservice you are trying to communicate with under your control so you can debug it to find out what it does with the request and how it comes to the conclusion to send a 400 response? How did you find out how requests for it need to be formatted?

Comment: @Philipp , I tried posting to the API through Postman which worked fine and I took its sample code snippet and tried it on my application. I am using the API from an end user perspective so I dont have an option to debug. Although, I have raised an incident to the provider for help. When posting from Postman, the content type is taking "multipart/form-data" whereas in my case when running from Chrome, I see the content type as urlencoded.